# Com CSS é possível controlar qual elemento vai ativar o Focus-Within de um Form?

Tags: html5, css3, formulário, ui

Existe alguma forma de determinar apenas com CSS qual `elemento` focado em específico vai ativar o `:focus-within` do `form`? Quero que apenas um `input` em específico ative a classe `form:focus-within {}` do `form`.

Pelo que percebi qualquer elemento que for focado dentro do `form` já vai ativar a regra `form:focus-within {}`, **porém eu gostaria que apenas o último `input` do `form` ativasse essa classe**.

Aqui tem um exemplo, veja que independente do `input` que eu clico o `form` já reconhece que um dos `inputs` dentro dele foi `focado`. Porém eu gostaria de controlar isso, mudando o `:focus-within` do `form` apenas quando o último `input` for `focado`.

Isso é possível só com CSS?

```css
form {
 border: 1px solid;
 color: gray;
 padding: 4px;
}

form:focus-within {
 background: #ff8;
 color: black;
}

form:focus-within::after {
 content: "Confira as informações antes de enviar!";
 display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
 color: red;
}

input {
 margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <label for="name">Name:</label>
 <input id="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
 <br>
 <label for="number">Number:</label>
 <input id="number" type="number" autocomplete="off"> <b>quero que apenas esse input ative o focus-within</b>
</form>
```

Comment: Se ao invés deles terem desenvolvido esse seletor level 4, tivessem optado pelo `:has()`, muita coisa se resolveria, além da sua necessidade aqui :) ... apesar que não sei se o :has suportaria algo como `:has(input:focus)`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vc entendeu bem o ponto, a ideia era usar o input filho para estilizar o form pai, até funciona, só que eu queria tentar controlar qual filho controla o pai, da forma que está no momento qq filho ativa o pai :/, com CSS acho que vamos ter que esperar alguma nova especificação

Comment: eu duvido muito que com CSS puro conseguirá algo, infelizmente só JS por enquanto

Answer (score -1):

Não é possível fazer isso apenas com CSS. O :focus-within seleciona o elemento pai mais próximo quando qualquer um dos seus filhos estiver em foco. Para controlar isso, você pode adicionar uma classe JavaScript para o último input quando ele estiver em foco e, em seguida, usar essa classe para ativar a regra de estilo desejada no formulário.

Answer (score -2):

OI, faz tempo porém não sei se conseguiu, tente esse

```css
form {
    border: 1px solid;
    color: gray;
    padding: 4px;
}

form:focus-within input:nth-child(5) {
    background: #ff8;
    color: black;
}

form:focus-within::after {
    content: "Confira as informações antes de enviar!";
    display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}

input {
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    <br>
    <label for="number">Number:</label>
    <input id="number" type="number" autocomplete="off"> <b>quero que apenas esse input ative o focus-within</b>
</form>
```

Comment: Como assim amigo? Acho que vc não entendeu a pergunta, eu quero que só o último input do form ative o estilo do focus-within do form... Não tem nada a ver com `nth-child()`. Repare que no seu próprio exemplo quando eu clico no primeiro input ele já ativa o estilo do form, que é justamente o que eu quero evitar

Comment: Olá, então explique melhor, quando vc quer que ative? em que momento? ao clicar no form? vai focar o último input? e se a pessoa clicar no primeiro o que é para acontecer? acredito que explicando a ação posso interpretar melhor.

Comment: Talvez vc não tenha visto essa frase na pergunta https://prnt.sc/w7sz0z acredito que a explicação lá foi o suficiente. Mas sinta-se a vontade para atualizar a sua resposta caso chegue em uma solução para o problema apresentado em detalhes na pergunta

Answer (score -3):

Olá! Tente colocar o atributo autofocus no último input do seu body, logo irá focar automaticamente nele quando você entrar na página.
Obs.: Não sei se era isso que você queria, mas espero ter ajudado.