# Alterar a borda do FORM quando o INPUT interno estiver em foco

Tags: css

Pode ser algo meio estúpido ou até uma pergunta duplicada, mas como tudo o que eu sei sobre `css` é na testada e não tenho nem ideia de como pesquisar no google, resolvi fazer essa pergunta.

É o seguinte, tenho o seguinte formulário:

```html
    <form class="form-inline my-0 my-lg-0 lozano-search">
        <input type="search" placeholder="buscar" aria-label="Buscar">
        <button type="submit"><img src="images/icon-search.svg"></button>
    </form>
```

Com o seguinte css:

```css
    .lozano-search {
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 200px;
        border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    }
```

Que gera esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero alterar o elemento pai, no caso o `form` quando o `input` estiver em foco, tipo isso:

```css
    .lozano-search input:focus .lozano-search{
       border: 2px solid #F67300;
    }
```

Para que fique com esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É exatamente para isso que exite a *pseudo-classe* `:focus-within`. Com ela ao focar em algum "elemento focável" dentro do `form` vc pode estilizar o próprio `form`, vc pode ler a documentação da Mozilla sobre isso aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem o exemplo da imagem acima:

```css
.lozano-search {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.lozano-search:focus-within {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline my-0 my-lg-0 lozano-search">
    <input type="search" placeholder="buscar" aria-label="Buscar">
    <button type="submit"><img src="images/icon-search.svg"></button>
</form>
```

---

**OBS**

O ponto contra é que vc não consegue controlar qual `input`, `button`, `link`, etc vai ativar o `:focus-within` do `form` pai, ou seja, se o form tiver 5 `inputs`, qualquer um deles que receber o foco vai ativar o `form` pai, ou se vc focar em um `<button>` tb vai ativar a o `form` pai, vc pode ler mais sobre isso nessa pergunta sem resposta: [Com CSS é possível controlar qual elemento vai ativar o Focus-Within de um Form?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/387245/com-css-%c3%a9-poss%c3%advel-controlar-qual-elemento-vai-ativar-o-focus-within-de-um-form)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso acima o ponto positivo é que vc não precisa do `button` dentro do form para fazer o `submit`, ele pode estar em qq lugar e mesmo assim clicando nele vc consegue enviar o form, é uma forma para vc tentar contornar esse comportamento.

---

**DICA**

Nessa outra resposta tem um exemplo mais sofisticado que pode te interessar, pelo menos para vc entender melhor a pseudo-classe e as possibilidades que ela oferece: [Mudar propriedades do pai se existir filho CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/396378/mudar-propriedades-do-pai-se-existir-filho-css/396404#396404)

Comment: Agora sei para que serve pseudo classes. Eu nunca havia usado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Hugo!

Comment: @AndreiCoelho sem problemas meu caro, fico feliz em ter ajudado, tem uma lista de todas as pseudo-classes no site da Mozilla, tem muita coisa interessante lá depois procure saber. Abs

Answer (score 0):

Assim?

Formulário:

```html
<form class="form-inline my-0 my-lg-0 lozano-search">
   <input class="input-pesquisa" type="search" placeholder="buscar" aria-label="Buscar">
   <button type="submit"><img src="images/icon-search.svg"></button>
</form>
```

Css:

```css
.input-pesquisa:focus{
   border: 2px solid #F67300;
}
```

Comment: Analisando a imagem que você postou, não irá te atender da forma que você espera. Não da para usar ".lozano-search:focus{..." pois o formulário não recebe o foco, mas sim o input. Do jeito que você quer, provavelmente você terá que usar o evento onfocus no input para chamar uma função javascript que altere o css.

Comment: Michell da para fazer só com CSS sim, se te interessar deixei uma resposta ai que acredito que vc vai gostar. Abs

Comment: Tambem não conhecia o :focus-within, vivendo e aprendendo. Show!